# Тире, двоеточие, запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, что поставить на место пропуска: тире, двоеточие или запятую:

1. "Знакомый был голос() высокий, немного срывающийся. И лицо тоже знакомое() круглые очки, высокие скулы и темные волосы."
2. "А вот и она() наверняка поджидала за углом"
3. "Он запоминал всех, кто ему помогал() может, когда-нибудь пригодится."
4. "Март поднялся, но не рискнул отпустить Мику() а вдруг убежит."
5. "Его лицо покрылось красными пятнами от негодования() эти дети совсем перестали его слушаться."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом предложение нужно двоеточие, т.к. дальше следует пояснение. Во втором предложении нужна запятая или восклицательный знак( если предложение произносится с восклицательной интонацией) т.к. в нем нет пояснения. В третьим предложении лучше поставить точку, т.к. при наличии запятой,вводное слово "может" будет относится к двум частям предложения. В четвертом предложении тоже нужна точка, оно по структуре закончено. В последнем, в бессоюзном сложном  предложении, нужно двоеточие, т.к во второй части указывается причина.